# How to write multiple arrays of a excel sheet to different excel sheet using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

In an excel sheet I have data in `A1:X1,A2:X2....A30:X30`. I have values like `120101`, `120102` in `AD1:AD30`. I want `xlsread` to read the data of `A1:X1`, and `xlswrite` with the name present in `AD1` i.e `120201`.
I want to do this for all arrays at a time and `xlswrite` them at a time.
                                                                                                       Here is the code I used for 5 array, (`A1:X5`) and `AD1:AD5`
(I want the code for 30 rows or else I should write 30 switch cases)

```
clc;
clear all;
format long
a=xlsread('entiredata.xls',1,'A1:X5');
k=size(a)
b= a.';
h=xlswrite('har.xls',b);
q=xlsread('har.xls',1,'A1:E24');
fname=xlsread('entiredata.xls','AD1:AD5');


for f=1:length(fname)
d=fname(f)
d
k=num2str(fname(f));

if f<6
  switch(f)
     case 1
         f=q(1:24);
      case 2
         f=q(25:48);
      case 3
         f=q(49:72);
      case 4
         f=q(73: 96);    
       case 5
         f=q(97:120);


      end


end

 nname=xlswrite(k,f.');
end
```

1 row value (i.e 24 values)

```
27.69   27.41   27.4    27.4    27.41   27.41   27.43   27.43   27.44   27.44   27.44   27.44   27.47   27.47   27.51   27.51   27.55   27.55   27.61   27.61   27.65   27.65   27.69   27.69
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this, as you there is no way to run your code without the files, But I guess it will work.

What I have done is just create a loop for each column you have (n variable) and just run your code for every column. The only change is that i create the string for reading with each column number in each iteration. Check it, and tell me if you dont understand something or doesnt work

```
clc;
clear all;
format long
n=30;
for ii=1:n
   a=xlsread('entiredata.xls',strcat('A',num2str(ii),':X',num2str(1)));
   b= a.';
   b
   k1=xlsread('entiredata.xls',strcat('AD',num2str(ii),':AD',num2str(1)));

   k=xlswrite(strct('data_',num2str(ii),'.xls'),b); 
end
```

Comment: NO it is'nt working. i have changed my code u might get the idea how i wrote. I will mail the file if u give u r mail id

Comment: @Frank You can mail me with the file and the .m files if you want (my email is in my profile) but it would be even better if you could post it in this SO question, so everybody can see it. Up to you :)

Comment: i cannot find your maild id pls comment here

Comment: @Frank It is better if you can upload it somewhere and post it here.

Comment: i posted 1 row values i.e 24 values copy the same for 30 rows and tell me i need the code its very urgent

Comment: Your  code xlswrite all the values in the variable 'b' in a single file. what i want is i want first 24 values into onefile and next 24 to the other and so on

Comment: @Frank I edited the aswer. You could figure the result in less than 5 seconds if you had just readed my aswer totally before. Please, dont ask again if you are not ready to work by yourself to figure it out.

Comment: i'm trying the code but not able to do it so is the reason i put the doubt here